# Clase Active a un botón

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un formulario, pero necesito que el botón donde estemos posicionados se quede marcado de otro color. intenté con `class="active"` pero ese botón se queda siempre activo aunque seleccione otro y esa no es mi idea, si no que cuando cambie de botón se quede de otro color.
Por ejemplo: Si tengo el botón A y el Botón B de color rojo, cuando de click al botón A se quede activo en color azul hasta que cambie al botón B.
Eso es posible?
Tengo este código al cuál le deseo implementar dicha solución

```
<div class="btn-group">
           <div class="btn-group">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Interacciones <span class="caret"></span></button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Imprimir interacciones</a></li>
                 <li><a onclick="findMothIntCsr();">Ver mis interacciones</a></li>
                 <li><a onclick="findMothPieCsr();">Gráfica general de interacciones</a></li>
               </ul>
             </div>
          <button type="button" onclick="findStaff();" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Mi Staff</button>
           <button type="button" onclick="justify();" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Justificar adherencia</button>
           <button type="button" onclick="admLetter();" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Acta administrativa</button>
           </div>
```

De hecho esta función si lo hace, cuando doy click cambia a un color más oscuro, pero el evento me trae en un div un formulario en AJAX que por supuesto hay que llenar, si doy click en un input el botón deja de aparecer oscuro y sale normal.

Comment: Son siempre dos botones o pueden ser más?

Comment: Son 4, uno de ellos es dropdown-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que está la etiqueta jQuery, aquí una solución rápida con el evento `.click()`, solo tienes que adaptarla a tu html, según los selectores que puedas utilizar:

```js
$(function() {
  var botones = $(".container button");
  botones.click(function() {
    botones.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>Primero</button>
  <button>Segundo</button>
  <button>Tercero</button>
  <button>Cuarto</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Pefecto Shaz! Hasta me emocioné con tu script. Saludos!